# iOS - UIBarButtonItem - Back Button title vertical position not adjusting

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, back-button

I am setting a custom font in my `UIBarButtonItem` objects using `UIAppearance`. This works fine and sets the font correctly. However, I do need to adjust the button title's vertical position to cater for the sizing of the new font.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Sketch Rockwell" size:12] forKey:UITextAttributeFont] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, 1.5) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The problem is that the title's vertical position is adjusted correctly in a regular `UIBarButtonItem`, but the back buttons on the navigation bar do not get adjusted. I presume that I am targeting the correct object in my code because its font gets updated, just not its title's vertical position.

Does anyone have an idea of how to target the back buttons directly?

Thanks

Brian

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I had this issue too, I fixed it by using:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, 1.5) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: It should be `UIBarMetricsDefault` and not `UIControlStateNormal`

Comment: How do I do this for iOS 7?

Comment: Ah my eyes betray me! It should be `setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment`, and  **NOT** `setTitlePositionAdjustment`